# How to show records in a different order

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm starting with this small PHP and mysql script. How would i make it show the tasks by the **taskupdated column**?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tasks2 where owner=72";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['ownername'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $row['tasktitle'];
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $row['taskdetails'];
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM tasks2 WHERE owner=72 ORDER BY taskupdated";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['ownername'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $row['tasktitle'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo $row['taskdetails'];
    echo '<hr />';
}

?>
```

If you want to sort them the other way, use `ORDER BY taskupdated DESC` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM tasks2 where owner=72 ORDER BY taskupdated`

Comment: And you can add ASC or DESC at the end to control whether it's sorted in ascending or descending order.